# How can I animate underline width from the right on mouseout?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS underline animation effect code on my menu.
I want to make a small change in it - I need it to close the same way it opens, only backwards. Now it opens from left to right and closes from both sides to the middle, and I need it to be closed from right to left.

Thanks

The code:

```
#header-outer header#top nav >ul ul li a { display: inline-block; }

#header-outer header#top nav >ul ul li a:after {
    transition: transform .3s ease-out,border-color .3s ease-out;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    content: '';
}

#header-outer header#top nav >ul ul li a:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

body [data-dropdown-style="minimal"] .sf-menu >li >ul { box-shadow: none !important; }

header#top .sf-menu li ul li a:hover,
html body[data-dropdown-style="minimal"] #header-outer:not([data-format="left-header"]) header#top nav > ul > li:not(.megamenu) ul a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
```

Comment: You are showing underline on hover right?

Answer (score 5):

I made this simple border animation that I think will help you archive your goal.

```css
ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

ul li a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Test animation</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test animation</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test animation</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test animation</a></li>
</ul>
```